# yum update to upgrade

Tags: linux, yum, openssl

I want to update openssl using `yum update` command.

I knew that `yum update` will update all packages.

I also knew that we can explicitly update packages like this.

```
# yum update {package-name-1}
```

If I want to update openssl using yum.

Can the following code is sufficient

```
# yum update openssl
```

Actually I don't have access to server, I am trying to find out the possible solutions to it.

If the above statement doesn't work, can some one suggest exact statement for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the command

```
yum update openssl
```

will update the openssl package to the latest available for your distribution release.

> update If  run without any packages, update will update every currently installed package.  If one
>                 or more packages or package globs are specified, Yum will only update the listed  packages.
>                 While updating packages, yum will ensure that all dependencies are satisfied. (See Specify-
>                 ing package names for more information) If the packages or globs specified match  to  pack-
>                 ages  which  are not currently installed then update will not install them. update operates
>                 on groups, files, provides and filelists just like the "install" command.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can I use this to update to specific version of openssl. Say the latest version is 1.0.1e but If I want to update it to 1.0.0i, can this be done. Or I have to do this manually.

Comment: @User222: I've never used it but there is `yum update-to` which may do what you want. http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum

Comment: @user222, this will work _only_ if the package is available for your distribution, and still in the repositories. Normally the repositories contain just the latest version supported by the distribution.